# iCloud and CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, icloud

I am trying to use iCloud with my iOS app. I have the app working on the individual devices but when I added iCloud nothing happened. I have looked all over the web and have found only one example which I did not understand. My app is iOS 5.0 and use core data to store the pages. Below is my app delegate and my view which I display it in. Sorry for the lack of knowledge when it comes to iPhone dev. Please help.
http://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/452

thank you

If anyone know/has a full working project of iCloud+CoreData I belive I can figure it out. Right now I just have code snip it's which I don't even know how they get called... If I have a full project I can step through it, so I can fully understand how it works.

The problem is I don't think anything is being called to update the view with the data and I don't belive it is sending it to the cloud but I don't know what to call...

PageFlipperAppDelegate.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "PageView.h"
    #import "SlideShowViewController.h"
    #import "PagesCollectionViewController.h"
    #import "UiWindowSubclass.h"

    @interface PageFlipperAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) PagesCollectionViewController *collectionViewController;
    - (void)saveContext;
    - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

    @end
```

PageFlipperAppDelegate.m

```
    #import "PageFlipperAppDelegate.h"

    @implementation PageFlipperAppDelegate

    @synthesize window;
    @synthesize managedObjectContext, managedObjectModel, persistentStoreCoordinator,collectionViewController;



    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.75];
        collectionViewController = [[PagesCollectionViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
        [(UINavigationController *)[[self window] rootViewController] pushViewController:collectionViewController animated:NO];


        [collectionViewController release];
        [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];


        return YES;
    }

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        //stopping timer since we're going to background
        //  [(UiWindowSubclass *)self.window stopTimer];
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
    }


    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { [self saveContext]; }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {

    }


    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application { [self saveContext];
    }

    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [window release];
        [managedObjectContext release];
        [managedObjectModel release];
        [persistentStoreCoordinator release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {

    }

    - (void)saveContext
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([self managedObjectContext])
        {
            if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
            {
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            } 
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - Core Data stack


    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        if (managedObjectContext != nil)
        {
            return managedObjectContext;
        }

        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

        if (coordinator != nil)
        {
            //if (IOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0")) {
            NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

            [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
                [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
            }];
            managedObjectContext = moc;

        }
        return managedObjectContext;
    }
    /**
     Returns the managed object model for the application.
     If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
     */
    - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
    {
        if (!managedObjectModel)
        {
            NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PageFlipper" withExtension:@"momd"];
            managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
        }    
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    /**
     Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
     If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.

    - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
        if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
        {
            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PageFlipper.sqlite"];

        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc = persistentStoreCoordinator;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            // Migrate datamodel
            NSDictionary *options = nil;

            // this needs to match the entitlements and provisioning profile
            NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:@"G88FQ4WK29.com.brandonsdesigngroup.3Doodles"];
            NSString* coreDataCloudContent = [[cloudURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data"];
            if ([coreDataCloudContent length] != 0) {
                // iCloud is available
                cloudURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:coreDataCloudContent];

                options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                           @"3Doodles.store", NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,
                           cloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey,
                           nil];
            } else {
                // iCloud is not available
                options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                           nil];
            }

            NSError *error = nil;
            [psc lock];
            if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
            {
                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
            [psc unlock];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"asynchronously added persistent store!");
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefetchAllDatabaseData" object:self userInfo:nil];
            });

        });


        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    - (void)mergeiCloudChanges:(NSNotification*)note forContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc {
        [moc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note]; 

        NSNotification* refreshNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"RefreshAllViews" object:self  userInfo:[note userInfo]];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:refreshNotification];
    }


    - (void)mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];

        // this only works if you used NSMainQueueConcurrencyType
        // otherwise use a dispatch_async back to the main thread yourself
        [moc performBlock:^{
            [self mergeiCloudChanges:notification forContext:moc];
        }];
    }
    #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

    /**
     Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
     */
    - (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
    {
        return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    }


    @end
```

viewController.h

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "CollectionViewController.h"
    #import "SlideShowViewController.h"
    #import "PagesDataSource.h"
    #import "PageView.h"
    #import "PageViewController.h"
    #import "PrototypeView.h"
    #import "QuickStart.h"

    @interface PagesCollectionViewController : CollectionViewController<quickStartDismiss,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
    {
        PagesDataSource *dataSource;
        PageViewController *viewController;
    @private NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController__ ;
    @private  NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext__;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    - (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext;
    - (IBAction)add:(id)sender;
    -(void)setShadowAndColor;
    -(void)playSlideShow;

    @property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL editMode;
    @end

    @interface PageView (CollectionViewItem)
    - (void)setRepresentedObject:(PVPage *)representedObject;
    - (PVPage *)representedObject;
    -(void)didHoldItem;
    -(void)duplicatePage;
    @end


    @interface PushController : UIViewController
    {}
    @end

    @interface toolBar : UIToolbar
    @end
```

viewController.m

```
    #import "PagesCollectionViewController.h"
    #import "PageFlipperAppDelegate.h"
    @implementation toolBar
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {}
    @end
    @implementation PagesCollectionViewController
    @synthesize editMode;
    @synthesize fetchedResultsController=__fetchedResultsController;
    @synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"integerKey"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"integerKey"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            QuickStart*stickieViewController = [[[QuickStart alloc]init]autorelease];
            stickieViewController.delegate = self;
            stickieViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentModalViewController:stickieViewController animated:YES];
        }

        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease],

                               [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(playSlideShow)]autorelease],

                               [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease],
                               nil]];

        [(CollectionView*)[self view] setCanReloadData:YES];
        [(CollectionView*)[self view]layoutSubviews];

    }
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
    {
        if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
        {
            return __fetchedResultsController;
        }

        /*
         Set up the fetched results controller.
         */
        // Create the fetch request for the entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"<sort key>" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorName, nil];

        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"<section name key path>" cacheName:@"<cache name>"];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        [aFetchedResultsController release];
        [fetchRequest release];
        [sortDescriptorName release];
        [sortDescriptors release];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }


    // because the app delegate now loads the NSPersistentStore into the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator asynchronously
    // we will see the NSManagedObjectContext set up before any persistent stores are registered
    // we will need to fetch again after the persistent store is loaded
    - (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }             

        if (note) {
            [(CollectionView*)[self view] setCanReloadData:YES];
            [(CollectionView*)[self view]layoutSubviews];
        }
    }
    -(void) playSlideShow{
        SlideShowViewController *slideShowViewController = [[[SlideShowViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
        NSMutableArray *tempArrayOfImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
        for (int i = 0; i < [[dataSource pages]count]; i++) {
            if ([[[dataSource pages] objectAtIndex:i] thumbnail] != nil) {
                [tempArrayOfImages addObject: [[[dataSource pages] objectAtIndex:i] thumbnail]];
            }

        }

        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:slideShowViewController animated:YES];
        [slideShowViewController setImagesInImageViewer:tempArrayOfImages];
    }
    -(void)dismissQuickStart{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    - (id)initWithManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
    {
        if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"CollectionView" bundle:nil]))
        {
            if (editMode == NO) {
                [self finishEditToolBars];
            }
            [self setTitle:@"Doodles"];
            viewController = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            dataSource = [[PagesDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
            CGSize itemViewMarginSize = CGSizeMake(25.0, 0.0);
            [(CollectionView *)[self view] setItemViewMarginSize:itemViewMarginSize];
            PrototypeView *pro = [[[PrototypeView alloc] init] autorelease];
            [(CollectionView *)[self view] setItemViewPrototype:pro];
            [(CollectionView *)[self view] setFlowDirection:CVFlowDirectionVertical];
            [(CollectionView *)[self view] setItemViewFrameSize:CGSizeMake(([(CollectionView *)[self view] bounds].size.width - 3*itemViewMarginSize.width)/3.4, ([(CollectionView *)[self view] bounds].size.height - 3*itemViewMarginSize.height)/3.6)];
            [self setShadowAndColor];
        }
        return self;
    }
    -(void)setShadowAndColor{
        CollectionView *collectionView = (CollectionView *)[self view];
        [collectionView setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [collectionView setShadowRadius:6.0f];
        [collectionView setShadowOpacity:0.5f];
    }

    - (void)add:(id)sender
    {

        [dataSource add:sender];
        CollectionView *collectionView = (CollectionView *)[self view];
        // [collectionView reloadData];
        //  [collectionView scrollItemIndexToVisible:[self countOfItemsInCollectionView:collectionView]-1 animated:NO];

        [collectionView.dataDelegate collectionView:collectionView didSelectItemAtIndex:[self countOfItemsInCollectionView:collectionView]-1];
        //CollectionViewController *c;
        //   [[c transitionToDetailViewController:[c collectionView:self detailViewControllerForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)[self countOfItemsInCollectionView:collectionView]-1] forItemView:[itemViews objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [self countOfItemsInCollectionView:collectionView]-1]]]];
        //  [c transitionToDetailViewController:self forItemView:collectionView.itemViews;
        editMode = NO;
        //collectionView.canUpdateLayout = YES;
        collectionView.canReloadData = YES;
        [(CollectionView*)[self view]layoutSubviews];



    }


    - (NSUInteger)countOfItemsInCollectionView:(CollectionView *)collectionView { return [[dataSource pages] count]; }

    - (id)collectionView:(CollectionView *)collectionView representedObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)itemIndex { 
        return [[dataSource pages] objectAtIndex:itemIndex]; 
    }

    - (void)collectionView:(CollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)itemIndex
    {

        if (editMode == YES) {
            [collectionView yellowdidSelectItemAtIndex:itemIndex];
            //  NSLog(@"edit");
        }else{

            PVPage *selectedPage = [[[dataSource pages] objectAtIndex:itemIndex]autorelease];
            PageView *pageView = [[[PageView alloc] init] autorelease];
            [pageView setRepresentedPage:selectedPage];

            //   UIImage *i = [UIImage imageWithData: [[pageView representedPage] thumbnail]];
            // UIImageView *ii = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:i]autorelease];

            [viewController setView:pageView];
            //  [(PageView*)[viewController view] setBackgroundStrokes:ii];
            //NSLog(@"selected page %@",selectedPage);
            // [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setHidden:YES];
            //   [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden:YES];   
            //   [[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setHidden:YES]; 
            PageFlipperAppDelegate *appDelegate = (PageFlipperAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            //  [(UiWindowSubclass *)appDelegate.window startTimer];
            [(UINavigationController *)[(UiWindowSubclass*)[appDelegate window] rootViewController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
            //  viewController = nil;
            // [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO];
        }    
    }
    - (BOOL)collectionView:(CollectionView *)collectionView canDeleteItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)itemIndex { 
        NSLog(@"itemIndex %u",itemIndex); 
        return YES; 

    }

    - (void)collectionView:(CollectionView *)collectionView didDeleteItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)itemIndex
    {
        [dataSource removePageAtIndex:itemIndex];
    }


    -(void)trash{
        // NSLog(@"trash");
        [(CollectionView *)[self view] trashitems];
    }
    -(void)done{

        [(CollectionView *)[self view]  yellowdidSelectItemAtIndexUndo];
        [(CollectionView *)[self view] shakedidRemoveSelectItemAtIndex];
        [(CollectionView *)[self view] donereset];
        [self finishEditToolBars];

    }
    -(void) finishEditToolBars{
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)] autorelease]];
        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(didHoldItem)] autorelease]];

        editMode = NO;
    }
    -(void)duplicatePage{
        NSArray *tempArray = [[[(CollectionView*)[self view] selectedItemsArray]copy]autorelease];
        //    for (int i =0; i<[[(CollectionView*)[self view] selectedItemsArray]count]; i++) {
        //        [(CollectionView *)[self view]  yellowdidSelectItemAtIndex:i];
        //        
        //    }
        [dataSource duplicatePage:[[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray]autorelease]];
        CollectionView *collectionView = (CollectionView *)[self view];
        editMode = NO;
        [self done];
        // [(CollectionView *)[self view]  yellowdidSelectItemAtIndexUndo];
        collectionView.canReloadData = YES;
        [collectionView layoutSubviews];



    }
    -(void)didHoldItem{
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done)] autorelease]];
        //    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(trash)] autorelease]];
        toolBar* tools = [[toolBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];
        tools.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        tools.opaque = NO;
        //tools.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        // create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
        NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

        // create a standard "add" button
        UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(trash)];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];
        [bi release];

        // create a spacer
        bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
        [buttons addObject:bi];
        [bi release];

        // create a standard "refresh" button
        bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize target:self action:@selector(duplicatePage)];
        bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:bi];
        [bi release];

        // stick the buttons in the toolbar
        [tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

        [buttons release];

        // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools] autorelease];
        [tools release];
        [(CollectionView*)[self view] setOldItemIndex:-1];
        editMode = YES;
        [(CollectionView*)[self view] setEditMode:YES];
        [(CollectionView*)[self view] shakedidSelectItemAtIndex];
    }
    -(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
        // NSLog(@"mem");
    }
    - (void)dealloc
    {   [dataSource release],dataSource = nil;
        [viewController release],viewController = nil;

        [super dealloc];
    }
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [ (CollectionView*) [self view] setCanReloadData:YES];
        [(CollectionView*) [self view]  layoutSubviews];
    }
    -(void) viewDidLoad{

        CollectionView *collectionView = (CollectionView *)[self view];
        collectionView.canReloadData = YES;
        [(CollectionView*)[self view]layoutSubviews];
        editMode = NO;
        collectionView.editMode = NO;



    }
    @end
```

Comment: You'd improve this question (and the chance that someone smart might answer it) by clearly stating a real question. "Nothing happened" isn't a question, and even with a +50 bonus, I doubt that anyone wants to pick through your code looking for something that might not work. Help us help you by telling us what you want to know.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work!

Comment: Obviously, but you can still explain *what* doesn't work. What do you expect the code to do? What does it do instead? What have you done so far? "Following the steps in the documentation, I've done 1, 2, 3, and 4, but my Core Data store still doesn't sync with iCloud; what could I be missing?" would be a better question than "nothing happened."

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to what exactly the problem you are observing might be? What errors are you seeing? Are there delegates that are not being notified? Does it work on one device but not update the other with the changes? I might be able to help if I knew what the symptoms were.

Comment: If anyone know/has a full working project of iCloud+CoreData I belive I can figure it out. Right now I just have code snip it's which I don't even know how they get called... If I have a full project I can step through it, so I can fully understand how it works.

Comment: There still isn't a question there. What do you expect to happen? What is not happening? What is happening instead? Consider cutting down the amount of code you post to only the relevant section of your problem.

Comment: The problem is I don't think anything is being called to update the view with the data and I don't belive it is sending it to the cloud but I don't know what to call...

Answer (score 4):

On the Apple developer forums the iPhoneCoreDataRecipes sample code is posted, which includes iCloud.

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126670?tstart=0

Comment: you should have a registered Apple's Dev account to access the forum. And it really helped me to make the app work.

Answer (score 3):

You can watch this year's WWDC 2012 Session 227 lecture (you can freely access these videos using your Apple Developer account), that will show how to correctly use Core Data and iCloud together, illustrating the correct application architecture, the way Core Data and iCloud should talk to each other and explaining all this stuff through a complete sample project.

**Edit**

The full source of the project is only available to **all** registered Apple developers under [this page](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_sample_code/wwdc_2012_session_code.dmg).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very controversial topic... I need to add iCloud with Core Data in my next application but it's a bit hard to start. I have done nothing but I found these documents very useful:

- [Using Core Data with iCloud Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011298)
- [Using iCloud in Conjunction with Databases](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW16)
- [Your Third iOS App: iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloud101/CodeListings/CodeListings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011317-CH8-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

It's not just controversial, it's not working adequately yet. If you are able to code the sample, you'll likely find that it only works on occasion. I wish I could write that it's solved and here is how you use it - maybe someone else can, but as of March 2012, I doubt it.

Still, it's interesting and instructive to code the sample, and the others in the dev site, so that you can learn what iCloud/core data is all about.

A lot of us are chomping at the bit for this to solidify.

You may want to try [Dox](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) from [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/) fantastic site. But you'll likely end up with the same frustration. Sometimes it works, mostly not.

Answer (score 2):

Blackpixel have upped a version of [Core Data Recipes with iCloud to Github](https://github.com/blackpixel/NSConferenceiPhoneCoreDataRecipes). It may have improvements over the version in the dev forums.

I've used the [dev forums version](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/126670?tstart=0) and found that it works, but takes some time to sync. Read the comments thread there (19 pages and counting) and make up your mind about it.